# Command for upgrading docker

Tags: upgrade, docker

Now my docker version is 0.9.0. I want to upgrade it to latest version due to some error

occuring with current version. so please suggest the apt command for this.

Comment: FYI 0.9.0 is the latest version. Perhaps you should ask about the specific error you're encountering?

Answer (score 11):

This should work in any Debian based distribution (Ubuntu, Linuxmint, etc)

Check current version

```
$ docker -v
Docker version 1.3.2, build 39fa2fa
```

Check installed packages in the system

```
# dpkg -l | grep docker
ii  lxc-docker                                   1.3.2                           amd64        Linux container runtime
ii  lxc-docker-1.3.2                             1.3.2                           amd64        Linux container runtime
```

Remove those packages

```
# apt-get remove --purge lxc-docker lxc-docker-1.3.2
```

Install new packages using Docker's preferred logic

```
# curl -sSL https://get.docker.com/ | sh
```

Add you user to the docker group

```
# sudo usermod -aG docker my_user
```

Confirm latest version

```
# docker --version
Docker version 1.6.2, build 7c8fca2
```

Comment: Note that on Linux Mint, the package name to remove is `docker-engine`.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Windows docker environment, use bellow PowerShell commands to upgrade existing environment into latest version.

```
Install-Module DockerProvider -Force

Install-Package Docker -ProviderName DockerProvider -Force
```

Use this [link](https://www.ntweekly.com/2018/04/22/install-docker-windows-server-2016-version-1709/) for more information's.